# why static variable return empty even though i have set it in other class?

Tags: java, selenium, static, testng

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class A{
    private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(A.class);
    public static String temp = "";
    
   @Test
    public static void someMethod(){
        JavascriptExecutor btn = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        btn.executeScript("document.getElementById('someBtn').click();");
        // B.otherMethod is called
        log.info("temp|"+temp);
    }
}
-----------------------------------------------------------------
org.springframework.stereotype.Controller

@Controller
public class B{
 
 @ResponseBody
 @RequestMapping(value = "/public/something/othermehtod", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public otherMethod(){
    A.temp = "helloworld";
  }
}
```

As the title suggest,

1. when i run this class using TestNG
2. a button at frontend is click and B.otherMethod is called

temp is empty despite the fact I have set it in class B. I do not understand why, hope someone can shade some light on it.

Things to note: Class A and B are separate java file. otherMethod is being call at the frontend by someMethod

Comment: Where do you call `otherMethod`? Also it don't have return type. It will cause compilation error.

Comment: Indeed. Please provide a [mcve] or it will be hard to help you.

Comment: @talex I have edit my question to explain how i call otherMethod

Comment: @user14857732: "at the frontend" is not a sufficient explanation. Especially when we're talking about the test. When you run **this specific** test then that's the only code that's executed. Why would running the tests in `A` ever touch `B.otherMethod`?

Comment: @JoachimSauer i have added more details, by editing my question

Comment: @user14857732: unit tests tend to not interact with an actual running instance of your code. They are meant to be self-contained: if you want to call some code in your unit test, your unit test should call that code! The reason you don't see anything is almost certainly because your test and your application are running in two distinct JVMs: they have nothing to do with each other except that they run some of the same code.

Comment: is it possible to make otherMethod in the same JVM as someMethod?

Comment: The path for your controller method is `.../othermehtod` (not `.../othermethod`. That looks important.

Comment: I have tried shifting the method from class B to class A , still it cant work. I dont understand, doesn't shifting the method to class A put it in the same JVM ?

Comment: @user14857732 - No it doesn't.   Basically, what you are trying to do *won't work*.  A unit test running in one JVM cannot look at the state of a class (e.g. its statics) in another JVM.  Not even if you are running identical versions of the same class in both JVMs.

Comment: @user14857732: what you're asking is similar to "I put this button in MS word, but when I press it my Internet Explorer doesn't react, why is that?": MS Word and Internet Explorer are two entirely separate programs that don't normally interact. And the same is true for your web application and your unit tests: the fact that they are compiled from some of the same code doesn't mean they "touch" each other. Please search for some tutorials on unit testing, that should clarify how they are supposed to be used.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I hear what you say, I have came up a solution below. why my question still -1?? which part of my question is still confusing??

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class A{
    
 private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(A.class);
  
  public static String otherMethod(){
    return "helloworld";
  }

 @Test
 public static void someMethod(){    
        String temp = otherMethod();
        log.info("temp|"+temp);
    }
}
```

By declaring the method directly in class A  will print helloworld. I hope this will help someone